# Add array also to the data object in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I want to concatenate `ALLActivity` with Data but I don't know how to achieve that.

```
const [ALLActivity, setAllActivity] = useState([]);
```

I have different input fields that I get using `onchange`. They are then stored in a useState  `ALLActivity`.

```
const getActivity = (e) => {
   setAllActivity({ ...ALLActivity, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
 };
```

I want to combine the fields if `ALLActivity` and id

```
const submitnewActivity = (e) => {
    const Data = {
       ALLActivity,  //What should I do to fix here
       { id: e },
    }
 };
```

```
axios
    .patch("edit-activity/",ALLActivity,  //I want pass id along like this

      {
        headers: headers,
      }
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
const submitnewActivity = (e) => {
    const Data = {
       ...ALLActivity,  
        id: e 
    }
 };
```

This will spread the ALLActivity object and then the id will be added to the data object.